# Query Parse for all the data in a table and placing into array

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am making a running app and would like to have a viewController in which the user has running tips and facts randomly display on the field. I would like to query parse for the objectIds to then reference the id and assign the label the tip or fact. Currently I have hard coded the Ids into the app but I would like that array to contain the results from the query the code is as follows:

```
func GetObjectID(){
    ObjectIDs = ["id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8"]
    RandomID = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(ObjectIDs.count)))

}


func TheInfo(){
    GetObjectID()

    var query : PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "FactsandTips")
    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(ObjectIDs[RandomID]){
        (ObjectHolder : PFObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in



        if (error == nil) {

            self.fact = ObjectHolder!.valueForKey("Fact") as? String

            self.tips = ObjectHolder!.valueForKey("Tips") as? Array





            if(self.tips.count > 0){

                self.factLabel.text = self.fact

                self.Button1.setTitle(self.tips[0], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                self.Button2.setTitle(self.tips[1], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                self.Button3.setTitle(self.tips[2], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

                self.Button4.setTitle(self.tips[3], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

            }



        } else {

            print("There is something wrong!")

        }



    }



}
```

I am using swift, Xcode7, and parse as my backend

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I use to query a Parse table, retrieve all results and add it all into an array.  I then use the array as the source for a pickerView.

```
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Drivers")
    query.addAscendingOrder("Name")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    self.astrDrivers.append(object["Name"]! as! String)
                }
            }
            self.pkvDriverTrack.reloadAllComponents()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Note the line `self.astrDrivers.append(object["Name"]! as! String)`.  This is adding the `Name` column of each record to my `self.astrDrivers` array.

If you wanted to do retrieve multiple columns, your best bet is to create a custom object like below:

```
class ObjectNewFact:NSObject {
   var column1:String = String() // You might want to choose more descriptive variable names (I just don't know what your column names are).
   var column2:Int = Int()
   // etc.
}
```

You could then create an array of `ObjectNewFact`s with a line like

```
var aFacts:[ObjectNewFact] = [ObjectNewFact]()
```

Then you could amend your routine to retrieve the data from Parse to:

```
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Drivers")
    query.addAscendingOrder("Name")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for object in objects {
                    var NewFact:ObjectNewFact = ObjectNewFact()
                    NewFact.column1 = object["Column1"] as! String
                    NewFact.column2 = object["Column2"] as! Int
                    self.aFacts.append(NewFact)  
                }
            }
            self.pkvDriverTrack.reloadAllComponents()
        } else {
            print("Error: \(error) \(error!.userInfo)")
        }
    }
```

Now you have an array full of facts.  You might want to go down this custom object approach because you can also include things like the Fact ID or how many times the fact has been shown (if you're keeping track of that sort of thing).  It provides a more flexible solution for any changes in the future.

I hope this helped.